# How to run an imported .jar file

Tags: java, eclipse

I want to use and modify the Project Mogwai ErDesigner (this [project](http://mogwai.sourceforge.net/erdesignerng.html))

You can download it [here](http://sourceforge.net/projects/mogwai/files/Mogwai%20ER-Designer%20NG/Release-3.0.0-M9-SNAPSHOT/mogwai-erdesignerng-3.0.0-M9-SNAPSHOT-standard.jar/download)

My progress so far. I made a Java project in eclipse. Then I imported the .jar file to the project. But I can't start the application.

[image]

[image]

**How am I able to start the project?**

UPDATE

The Manifest file says

> Main-Class: com.izforge.izpack.installer.Installer

But the **same error** appears

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If the jar file is an executable jar file it should have a meta-inf file.  In that file there will be the name of the class that is run as the executable for the jar.  Select that file in your project and select Run as Java Application.

EDIT:

I was able to get the application to run by doing the following:
- Create a new Java Project in eclipse

- Create a new folder called lib and add the jar file to this folder
- Add the jar file to the project's class path (right click on the project and select Properties->Java Build Path->Libraries->Add Jars
- Find this class in the Package Explorer and right click and select Run as Application

[image]

Comment: it is still not working, please have a look at the UPDATE

Comment: Have you been able to get this to work with the above edit?

Answer (score 0):

What about starting from command line:

```
java -jar filename.jar
```

if it needs help about main class then try with path:

```
java -cp filename.jar full.package.name.ClassName
```

Answer (score 0):

You downloaded an installer JAR (IzPack is used for bundling a Java application in an installer). You have two options:

1. Download the plain ZIP file and unzip it add the files to your project and class path. Then right click on the project and select 'Run As'. It should give a list of Main classes, select your class.
2. From outside eclipse run the JAR file and install the software into a folder. Add the files from that folder to the eclipse project and class path and follow similar steps as above.